# Использование Tomcat для организации домашнего сервера

Tags: tomcat, ddns

Разработано web-приложение, которое развернуто в папке «webapps» Tomcat 9.0. В папке «webapps» находятся папка «PhotosClassifier», содержащая файлы, передаваемые браузеру, и файл PhotosClassifier.war. 
Приложение работает на домашнем компьютере в режиме имитации с доменным именем localhost:8080/PhotosClassifier.

При этом файл Tomcat server.xml содержит следующие описатели:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Теперь желательно проверить работу приложения с удаленного компьютера, то есть использовать домашний сервер на базе Tomcat 9.0.
Для этого зарегистрировался на сайте «no-ip», выбрал доменное имя, скачал и установил приложение «DUC», которое периодически пeредает серверу «no-ip» текущий IP-адрес компьютера.
Вопрос: какие изменения в файлах Tomcat необходимо сделать, чтобы приложение запускалось? Нужно ли, чтобы компонента доменного имени третьего уровня совпадала с именем папки «PhotosClassifier»?

Comment: а разве без этого tomcat не стартует? по факту ничего менять в tomcat не нужно. его нужно запустить и все. что бы люди могли достучатся из вне нужно открыть порт `8080` на вашем роутере если такой есть.

Comment: Спасибо, Томкат должен обрабатывать запросы! Причина отсутствия доступа в том, что мой провайдер держит мой компьютер внутри своей подсети, а программа no-ip «DUC» передает своему серверу адрес этой подсети, а не текущий адрес моего компьютера. Поэтому вместо обращения к Томкату no-ip сервер обращается к серверу провайдера, который не имеет задачи еще кого-то искать внутри подсети.